# Require count of fields in mysql

Tags: mysql

Please help me out
I have a column Delay_Reason in which I have values like below. values may end with ";#" or may be not.

```
DT1-Increased_CT_Reason_Start_to_Accept

ERIC_Drive Test Taking too Long;#ERIC_Lack Of GSC Resources/Queuing  DT  Drives;#ERIC_Cluster Having Too Many RF Issues Needing Tuning;#
ERIC_Drive Test Taking too Long;#ERIC_Lack Of GSC Resources/Queuing DT Drives;# 
ERIC_Drive Test Taking too Long;#
```

I have to count delay_reason.

My desired output is

```
DT1-Increased_CT_Reason_Start_to_Accept                   count  

ERIC_Drive Test Taking too Long                            3  
ERIC_Lack Of GSC Resources/Queuing  DT Drives              2
ERIC_Cluster Having Too Many RF Issues Needing Tuning      1
```

Comment: What does `a` only appear twice in the count?  Have you tried something yet?

Answer (score 4):

One trick you can use is to compare the length of the `Delay_Reason` column against the length of the same column with individual letters removed.  Then, sum up this difference over the whole table to get the number of occurrences.

```
SELECT 'a' AS Delay_Reason,
       SUM(CHAR_LENGTH(Delay_Reason) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(Delay_Reason, 'a', ''))) count
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'b',
       SUM(CHAR_LENGTH(Delay_Reason) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(Delay_Reason, 'b', '')))
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'c',
       SUM(CHAR_LENGTH(Delay_Reason) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(Delay_Reason, 'c', '')))
FROM yourTable
```

**Demo here:**

## SQL Fiddle

**Update:**

If you want to make the above query work for terms which are longer than a single character, you just need to normalize using the length of the terms being searched:

```
SELECT 'Los NE abc' AS Delay_Reason,
       SUM(CHAR_LENGTH(Delay_Reason) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(Delay_Reason,'Los NE abc','')))
           / CHAR_LENGTH('Los NE abc') AS count
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Angeles',
       SUM(CHAR_LENGTH(Delay_Reason) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(Delay_Reason,'Angeles','')))
           / CHAR_LENGTH('Angeles')
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'California',
       SUM(CHAR_LENGTH(Delay_Reason) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(Delay_Reason,'California','')))
           / CHAR_LENGTH('California')
FROM yourTable
```

Here is a demo of this query:

## SQLFiddle

Comment: solution will work only when only two delay reason are there like a;#b. It may happen that delay_reason of a or b or c can be anywhere i meant it can be a;#;b;#c or b;#a;#c, c;#b;#a.

Comment: Then you asked an unclear question, with sample data which does not reflect what the real problem is.  Update your question.

Comment: clever solution +1

Comment: Hi above solution is not working if we have values like "Los NE abc;#Angeles;#California"

Comment: @user2503377 I have my query updated and it is now working for search terms of any length now, q.v. the new Fiddle.

Comment: I have changed to the actual data... I have tried but not working. its counting the character and doing minus... result set is coming wrong

Comment: Create a Fiddle with your actual data and paste the link, I will have a look.  No, I will not update my answer again!  You changed your question three times and it is NOT fair to SO users to be asking them to keep updating.

Comment: I have provided a sample data in my question (edited my original question) by this you can have idea... I will modify the solution given by you according to the situation

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen:- Apology for the same

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen        http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ca143/7  count is coming wrong for "ERIC_Lack Of GSC Resources/Queuing  DT  Drives" do not know why

Comment: Its working there was space in between of ERIC_Lack Of GSC Resources/Queuing DT Drives that is why it not showing up the correct values. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Delay_Reason,COUNT(*)
FROM test      
GROUP BY Delay_Reason;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the database is storing multiple values in one field. The current schema violates 3rd normal form.

One solution is to run a query to normalise your data and then run normal aggregate queries on that query. substring_index can be used for this purpose.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/295f39/1)

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable (`Delay_Reason` varchar(512));

INSERT INTO yourTable (`Delay_Reason`)
VALUES
    ('ERIC_Drive Test Taking too Long;#ERIC_Lack Of GSC Resources/Queuing DT Drives;#ERIC_Cluster Having Too Many RF Issues Needing Tuning;#'),
    ('ERIC_Drive Test Taking too Long;#ERIC_Lack Of GSC Resources/Queuing DT Drives;# '),
    ('ERIC_Drive Test Taking too Long;#') ;


select delay_reason, count(*) count from (
    /* 
        normalise the data
        add as many substring_index union all elements as required
        */
    select SUBSTRING_INDEX(delay_reason, ';#', 1) AS delay_reason from yourTable
    union all
    select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(delay_reason, ';#', 2), ';#', -1) AS delay_reason from yourTable
    union all
    select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(delay_reason, ';#', 3), ';#', -1) AS delay_reason from yourTable
    union all
    select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(delay_reason, ';#', 4), ';#', -1) AS delay_reason from yourTable
    union all
    select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(delay_reason, ';#', 5), ';#', -1) AS delay_reason from yourTable
    union all
    select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(delay_reason, ';#', 6), ';#', -1) AS delay_reason from yourTable
    union all
    select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(delay_reason, ';#', 7), ';#', -1) AS delay_reason from yourTable
    union all
    select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(delay_reason, ';#', 8), ';#', -1) AS delay_reason from yourTable
    union all
    select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(delay_reason, ';#', 9), ';#', -1) AS delay_reason from yourTable
    union all
    select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(delay_reason, ';#', 10), ';#', -1) AS delay_reason from yourTable
) delay_reasons
/* remove empty values */
where delay_reason <> ''
group by delay_reason
order by count desc;
```

-- example results

delay_reason    count

ERIC_Drive Test Taking too Long 3

ERIC_Lack Of GSC Resources/Queuing DT Drives    2

ERIC_Cluster Having Too Many RF Issues Needing Tuning   1

If you have the rights to change the schema you could also normalise the data. [Search Google for third normal form explained](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=third%20normal%20form%20explained)